# return next(self._sampler_iter) # may raise StopIteration

Tags: python, iterator, pytorch

Instead of using `enumerate(data loader)` for some reason, I am creating iterator for the data loader. In the `while` loop shown below, it gives me `StopIteration` error.

Minimalistic code that depicts the cause:

```
loader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=args.batch_size)
dataloader_iter = iter(loader)
while(dataloader_iter):
    X, y = next(dataloader_iter)
    ...
```

What would be the correct condition (to specify within the while loop) to check if the iterator is empty?

Comment: Note, `enumerate` creates an iterator, ie an `enumerate` object. But of course it can raise StopIteration, that's how iterators work. The idiomatic way to handle this is to use a `try-except StopIteration`

Comment: But why are you iterating like this? Why not `for X, y in dataloader_iter`?

Comment: Note, unlike in other languages, the iterator protocol in Python doesn't stipulate any way to check if an iterator is empty, a là Java's `hasNext`, the equivalent is the rasing of a `StopItertation` exception. Python will often rely on exceptions where other similar languages might provide an explicit way to check. Note, you *could* use the second argument to `next` to provide some sentinel value, e.g `next(iterator, None)` but that would not be idiomatic

Comment: The reason why I am iterating like this is because there is a corrupt entry (dimension mismatch) inside my dataset. So, whenever I was doing ```enumerate(dataloader)```, it was throwing some error. Now, I am using a ```try-catch``` around ```next(dataloader_iter)``` to skip that malicious entry.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. You could still use enumerate and a for loop. These would be exactly equivalent to what you are doing

Comment: Well, I can't give you the example because the dataset is big and ```enumerate``` was always failing when it reached a particular entry. The only workaround was to skip that entry using ```try-catch``` around ```next(dataloader_iter)```

Comment: Ah the *unpacking* was failing. Ok, well using this is a simple enough solution. Note, you can *still* use enumerate, that simply returns an iterator (i.e. `enumerate` objects are iterators)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python it's standard in a lot of cases to use exceptions for control flow.

Just wrap it in a try-except:

```py
loader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=args.batch_size)
dataloader_iter = iter(loader)
try:
    while True:
        x, y = next(dataloader_iter)
        ...
except StopIteration:
    pass
```

If you want to catch some other errors inside the while loop, you can move the try-except inside, but you must remember to break out of the loop when you hit a `StopIteration`:

```py
loader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=args.batch_size)
dataloader_iter = iter(loader)
while True:
    try:
        x, y = next(dataloader_iter)
        ...
    except SomeOtherException:
        ...
    except StopIteration:
        break
```

Comment: Can I flip the order of ```try``` and ```while```?

Comment: The try-except likely should go inside the while loop body

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga There are some cases where you might want more control and use a `while` loop. But yeah, I agree that if you can get away with the `for` loop, then that would be preferred.

Comment: Yes I was misunderstanding the OP, I thought the call `enumerate(loader)` was failing

Answer (score 0):

You can change

```
X, y = next(dataloader_iter)
```

with

```
try:
    X, y = next(dataloader_iter)
except StopIteration:
    dataloader_iter = iter(data.DataLoader(...))
    X, y = next(dataloader_iter)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).